# Why does this simple C command line tool always exit without working?

Tags: c, xcode

I've just typed in an example from K&R...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int c, nl;

    nl = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {

        if (c == '\n') {
            ++nl;   
        }



    }

    printf("new lines=> %d\n", nl);

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I build & run, I get...

```
minimac:~ alex$ /Users/alex/Documents/K\&R/build/Debug/K\&R ; exit;
```

As you may be able to gather, running off the Mac OS X Terminal, if that means anything.

Why doesn't this ever prompt for input?

### Update

Here is how I started my project, on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

- Ran Xcode
- Started new project "command line tool" and called it `K&R`
- Typed in the code into `main.c`
- Hit the big button above "build & run"
- Double clicked `K&R` and Terminal was launched with the output above

I might also state that I have been using interpreted languages pretty much my entire life, so I am new to this compiling process.

When I use `gcc` to compile from the Terminal, I can run the program with `./a.out`. However, once I type, I don't know how to tell the program *I'm done, now please tell me how many lines have I typed in*.

Here is a screenshot of my Terminal...

[image: Terminal]
<sub>(source: [alexanderdickson.com](http://alexanderdickson.com/hosted/stackoverflow.com/terminal-k-r.png))</sub>

Comment: works like a charm here on snow leopard; just compiling&running with `gcc test.c; ./a.out` at least.

Comment: @mvds Damn, it must be an Xcode thing, somehow.

Comment: So what exactly *are* you doing? What command line are you using to compile? What command line are you using to run? What's the actual output of both the compiler and your program when it's run?

Comment: Can you show `cat filename.c` as well as the commands you use to compile and execute the source, along with output?  Basically, can you show a terminal dump?

Comment: Hey guys, I'm going to add some more to the question.

Comment: Maybe change your directory name to something other than `K&R`, i.e., without the `&` in it?  The output suggests that Xcode is correctly escaping the `&`, but it's better to be sure.

Comment: OK, I just did what you said in your steps, and I am able to type into the terminal.  However, before I get to see the output from the program, the terminal is closed (because of the `exit;`).  I added a `#include <unistd.h>` at the beginning and `sleep(2);` right before `return 0;`, and I can see the correct output.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to actually use the `gcc` command line, so that you become familiar with how it works. Especially if you're compiling command line example programs from K&R. Once you're comfortable with that, *then* you can graduate to using Xcode and you will understand what's happening underneath.

Comment: @ggg Thanks, I think I may try that. Is there a way to use the Xcode IDE, and then jump to Terminal and compile with `gcc`?

Comment: @alex, I don't see why not, as long as you know where the files you're creating are stored.

Comment: programs like these generally just compile with `gcc file.c -o file`, run with `./file` (or just take the default: `a.out`)

Comment: @ggg OK, one more question, thanks for your patience! I compiled the same file `main.c` using `gcc` from Terminal, and it produced `a.out`. If I type `a.out` I get `command not found`. How do I then run this file from the CL?

Comment: @ggg OK, that seems to work, and I can type, but how do I *fire* the event to make it display how many new lines there when `\n` won't do it? (apologies for the JavaScript analogy!)

Comment: @alex http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character, Ctrl-D.

Comment: @Jaanus Thanks for the link; it seems I have a lot to learn! That seems to make the program ran fine, I think it may have been that all along. Please post an answer so I can accept. And thanks to everyone else you helped.

Comment: @alex what does the above code ? Counts the number of new line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I just did what you said in your steps, and I am able to type into the terminal.  However, before I get to see the output from the program, the terminal is closed (because of the `exit;`).  I added a `#include <unistd.h>` at the beginning and `sleep(2);` right before `return 0;`, and I can see the correct output.

Here is the complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int c, nl;

    nl = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {

        if (c == '\n') {
            ++nl;   
        }



    }

    printf("new lines=> %d\n", nl);
    sleep(2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference on mine. Also, apologies if this is a stupid question, but after the `exit` on the CL, I can type whatever I want into Terminal with new lines. Is this standard? Thanks

Comment: @alex: it's not a stupid question.  The program is waiting to read stuff on standard input, and once it is done reading, it prints out the numbers of lines.  So, you enter a bunch of lines, and then type `ctrl-D` to send `EOF` to it.  Then, the program reports the number of lines on standard output, and exits.  Xcode is running two programs in the terminal: your program, followed by `exit`, which exits the terminal (the shell actually).  So as soon as your program prints the output, it's done, and `exit` exits the terminal.  I think you're confused about how things are working.  ...

Comment: @alex: I suggest you compile my program in Xcode, run it, and then type a bunch of lines in the open terminal, followed by `ctrl-D`.  You will then see the output, and then the terminal will wait for about 2 seconds and then go away.  Or, you can open a terminal manually, go to the directory containing the program, run the program, and then do what I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing this in Xcode. Not sure how Xcode handles stdin/out and what project template you are using. You should have all this in a simple .c file and just gcc it yourself without Xcode and see what happens then.

Edit: in Unix console, you press Ctrl-D to end stdin input to a command line program. [Wikipedia has more.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm using the template *command line tool*, and have used this in the past fine with input from the command line.